# ngx-sharebuttons npm not working with angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I am facing this issue with version 15 of angular
I try with the older version of ngx-sharebuttons (13,12, and 11 too) but the issue is the same there is nothing in the description about which version I have to use for angular 15

this is error
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C13eV.png)

here is my pakege.json
[pakege.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upweK.png)

- i try to install older version of ngx-sharebuttons
- I set up a fresh project for it

but the issue is the same

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for Angular v15
follow the steps:-
install version 12 of ngx-sharebuttons
install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.0" because by default it will install v 0.13.0
if you are using CSS in the angular project so dont import styles in Style.css import them on Angular.json under the styles
problem solved Happy coding
credit to https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons/issues/646

Comment: you are reposting my answer from GitHub man this answer was written by me

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't realize it was you, but I think if you know the solution, you need to share it.

Comment: Yeah but you did thanks man